# DocumentStore.OpenSession("InvalidDatabase") does not throw an exception

Tags: ravendb

In RavenDB, when I call DocumentStore.OpenSession("invalid database name here"), it does not throw an exception.  But rather opens a session to the system (default) database instead.  Is this by design?  Is there some setting I can change to make it throw an exception instead?

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT by design, and shouldn't be happening.
You should get an error on read / writer.